# How much time - how long

Tags: questions

Are both sentences correct? Do both share the same meaning? How do native speakers say about it?

> (1) How much time does it take to get from Shanghai to New York City?
> (2) How long does it take to get from Shanghai to New York City?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the question *"How **long/much time** ... take to do something,"* you'd respond

> *"(It takes) **X** hour/s"*

and so indicating an amount of time.

That's why I think native speakers would choose to say either *"long"* or *"much time"* interchangeably.

Also note that *"How **much time** do you need to do something?"* is so identical as *"How **long** do you need to do something [for]?"*